# Updating a row cell to an old value

Tags: php, mysql, database

**Issue fixed: The browsers are caching the GET requests. Adding in a random value into the jQuery fixes the issue. E.G:**

```
$.get(templateDir + "/inc/quote-update.php", { FlightID: FlightID, returnorigin: valuefrom, returndestination: valueto, returnpax: valuepax, returndate: valueret, "_": $.now()},
```

I've looked everywhere for a solution to this but I cannot find it. I apologise if this has been posted before.

The problem is this. When a user visits the website, they search for a flight. The details are stored in the database. This works fine.

The user is then able to change and add to their flight. This works fine - except for the passenger numbers.

For some reason, I am experiencing a strange bug with updating the number of passengers field. What happens is if you change the value to a value it has been ***previously***, it will not update. If you change it to a value it has ***not been previously***, it will successfully update.

For example, if the user initially searches for a flight for 6 passengers, then changes it to 4 passengers - they cannot then change it back to 6 passengers. They can, however, change it to 3, or 5, or 7 etc etc.

This is how I've setup the field in phpmyadmin:

```
4   pax bigint(20)      UNSIGNED    No  None
```

And this is my code:

```
<?php

    $FlightID = isset($_GET["FlightID"]) ? $_GET['FlightID'] : null;

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename', 'database-table', 'afgafha', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
                                                                                                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    // Start a counter for errors
    $error = 0;

    if (!is_null($FlightID)) {

            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM database-table WHERE FlightID = ?");
            $stmt->execute(array($FlightID));

            if ($stmt->rowCount() <= 0){ 

                        // Do Nothing //

                                        } elseif ($stmt->rowCount() == 1){      

                                                        $origin = isset($_GET['origin']) ? $_GET['origin'] : null;
                                                        $destination = isset($_GET['destination']) ? $_GET['destination'] : null;
                                                        $pax = isset($_GET['pax']) ? $_GET['pax'] : null;       
                                                        $depdate = isset($_GET['depdate']) ? $_GET['depdate'] : null;                   


                                                            if (!is_null($origin) && !is_null($destination) && !is_null($pax) && !is_null($depdate)){

                                                                    $data = array($origin, $destination, $depdate, $pax, $FlightID);  
                                                                    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE database-table SET origin=?, destination=?, depdate=?, pax=? WHERE FlightID=?");
                                                                    $stmt->execute($data);

                                                                    $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

                                                                    echo $affected_rows.' were affected';
                                                                    print_r ($data);

                                                            } else {
                                                                    // Validation failed
                                                                    $error++;
                                                            }

                                        } else { 
                                                $error++;           
                                        }
    } else {
            $error++;
    }
    if($error > 0) {

    }
    ?>
```

Does anybody have any ideas? I'm sorry if this is a really noob problem, but this was my first time making a PHP/SQL application myself.

And in advance - thank you!

Comment: Does it give you any error? Or it just leave the row unchanged?

Comment: Does the mysql log show something? Have you tried running directly the `update`, without using php?

Comment: Nope, I'll try that. I don't have access to my mysql logs :(

Comment: It always works when doing it in phpmyadmin without the PHP. Also, if you look in the console, you can see the AJAX is always sending the correct values to the PHP script too, so it's not a mix up there. The issue therefore I am 99% sure lies with my code above.

Comment: Are the query you run though phpMyAdmin and the one which is sent by php the same?

Comment: Yes. All I did was remove changing the other values also. So I was only updating the passenger numbers, not the other values. I've also ran the PHP script directly, negating everything except the PHP itself, and the issue persists.

Comment: I'm now having this issue with any of the fields and not just the passenger field. I can't get my head around this. It's not my jQuery. Also, because it prints the data, it is finding the matching row and it is running the query. It just doesn't "always" work. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. Bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

How is wpdev_flights defined? I guess it could have to do with your primary key... How does the table look like after you run the script a few times? Is there more then one row in the table for a single FlightID?
If there is more then one row present this would explain the behaviour. UPDATE will not do anything if a row matching the values is present.

Comment: How is it defined? It's just a table so I'm not sure what you mean, I forgot to scramble that bit though, if you look in my PDO statement the bit that says "sfshsfh" is what was "wpdev_flights" so maybe that caused confusion.

The table looks exactly as it did before, and it's not duplicating or anything like that, there are no multiple rows with the same ID.

Comment: He is asking about the `CREATE wpdev_flights` statement, so we can see the exact definition of your table's fields

Comment: I created the table manually in phpmyadmin. Shall I just copy and paste the structure from phpmyadmin?

Comment: Here is my structure, hope it helps. The fields "pax" and "Rpax" are the issue, as you can see I've tried to fiddle how I've setup the pax field. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/20205486/db-structure.JPG

Comment: Hmm. If "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM database-table WHERE FlightID = 'someID'" always gives 0 or 1 I'm at a loss here. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's stupid, but you have `pax` and `Rpax` fields in your table and you are updating a field named `returnpax` in the php code.

**EDIT:**

Just to share this information, you can use the `cache: false` setting in your JQuery call to avoid caching. It does basically the same thing you do with `$.now()`, but sounds cleaner to me. Glad you solved, anyway.

Comment: Good spot! But I don't think that's the problem. I've shown you code for updating the return flight, the code for updating the single flight is the same but instead of Rpax its just pax, I just checked the code for that update and it also says "pax". So that code is correct but for some reason I wrote it wrong for the return pax. Hope that makes sense and sorry for the confusion. Edit: I've fixed that in the code and replaced it above. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so you have the two funcions which are similar, one updates `pax` and the other updates `Rpax`, both are written correctly and the error in the posted code is just a typo? Plus, I'm still wondering if you have an error or just an "untouched" row.

Comment: Yep :) Would it help to give you a live example? Go here: http://jetbookingdirect.com/dev/sendmail/?FlightID=50d42bb9deac3

With that flight, the passenger number for the first leg was originally 4. I changed it to 6. I now can not change it back to 4. No error messages so far as I can see either.

Comment: I tried changing it back and forth a couple of times, it always gives me "Update successfull" and shows the correct number of passengers. Do you mean that in the DB things are different?

Comment: I can see you have, now I'm just more confused. Currently it's on "4". I now can't change it back to 6, no matter what I do. And nope the database always shows the same too.